# $ meaning in Android.mk

Tags: android.mk

This morning when I was going through Android.mk file. 
I was just wondering what does $ in the following means

For Example in android.mk

**LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)**

**include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)**

I just have this doubt when do we use the $ in writing the android make file. 
To call the script that is previously defined by the built system or To call macros or... When?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can take this as a shell prompt, that you use to call macro function, get predefined variable value etc.
e.g. `LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)` is used to return the path of the current directory, the macro function 'my-dir', provided by the build system.
More about [android.mk](http://www.kandroid.org/ndk/docs/ANDROID-MK.html)